# I'm struggling with a collisionless plasma textbook problem. Calculating the longitudinal dielectric function from the distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plasma-physics, dielectric, kinetic-theory, dispersion

The problem is:

> Given the distribution of the electrons
> $$
> f_0(\mathbf{p}) = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\frac{mun_e}{(p^2 + m^2u^2)^2}
> $$
> find longitudinal dielectric function and the dispersion equation for longitudinal waves.

According to the textbook longitudinal dielectric function can be found using the equation
$$
\varepsilon_l(\omega, k) = 1 + \frac{4\pi e^2}{k^2}\int\frac{1}{\omega - \mathbf{k}\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{k}\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \mathbf{p}}\ d\mathbf{p},
$$
where $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{p}/m$.

I've found
$$
\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \mathbf{p}} = -\frac{un_e}{m^4\pi^2}\frac{4\mathbf{v}}{(v^2 + u^2)^3},
$$
and then substituted it in the equation above to obtain
$$
\varepsilon_l(\omega, k) = 1 -\frac{32e^2un_e}{k^2m}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{v^2}{(v^2 + u^2)^3}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\frac{kv\cos{\theta}}{\omega - kv\cos{\theta}}\sin\theta\ d\theta dv =\\ 1 -\frac{4u}{\pi}\frac{\omega_{Le}^2}{k^2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\omega}{kv}\ln\left(\frac{\omega + kv}{\omega-kv}\right)-2\right)\frac{v^2\ dv}{(v + iu)^3(v - iu)^3},
$$
where
$$
\omega_{Le}^2 = \frac{4\pi e^2 n_e}{m}.
$$
Using contour integration, where I used a large semicircle contour with small arcs around $v = \pm \omega/k$, I then obtained

$$
\varepsilon_l(\omega, k) = 1 - \omega^2_{Le}\left(\frac{1}{(\omega+iku)^2} + \frac{2iku}{(\omega^2 + k^2u^2)^2} - \frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{k^2u^2}\left(\frac{\omega}{iku}\ln\left(\frac{\omega + iku}{\omega-iku}\right)-2\right)\right).
$$

However, in the textbook the answer is given as
$$
\varepsilon_l(\omega, k) = 1 - \frac{\omega^2_{Le}}{(\omega+iku)^2}.
$$
I specifically tried to change my answer to look close, but I don't understand how to get this result. Maybe my approach is wrong somewhere. I tried to explain it as detailed as possible for a stack question.

Could someone help me find the mistake?

Comment: Why is the textbook answer complex? A priori you are integrating a real function, so the result should be real.

Comment: Probably the problem is how the contour bypasses the poles. As I remember, the prescription for such problems is to add a small positive imaginary part to $\omega$. This means that the contour should pass one of the poles in upper half-plane and the other one in lower half-plane.

Comment: @E.Anikin That's it I think. Also, should I put the absolute value in the logarithm, because it's the integral of 1/x essentially?

Comment: @LPZ Oh, I see. But my solution is also complex. Maybe the mistake here is that I didn't put the absolute value in the logarithm when integrating 1/x

Comment: @LPZ - There are poles in here to integrate out, which automatically results in complex numbers.

Comment: @coloboquito - I will give you a hint.  If you put in proper integration limits (i.e., $\pm \infty$) and treat it one-dimensionally, the analytical solution is extremely simple.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks, your suggestion inspired me and I've managed to solve it using cylindrical coordinates instead of spherical! It became almost trivial compared to spherical mess!

Comment: @coloboquito - Yep, longitudinal electrostatic waves have $\mathbf{k}$ parallel to $\delta \mathbf{E}$.  That is, they are linearly polarized and the fluctuations oscillate parallel/anti-parallel to the wave vector direction.

Comment: @E.Anikin thanks, this approach worked after I used cylindrical coordinates

Comment: @LPZ your comment made me notice that my original wrong answer is actually completely real. The logarithm is actually arctan in disguise! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by writing dielectric function as the limit
$$
\varepsilon_l(\omega, k) = 1 +\frac{4\pi e^2}{k^2}\lim\limits_{\Delta \rightarrow 0}\int\frac{\mathbf{k}}{\omega + i\Delta - \mathbf{k}\mathbf{v}}\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \mathbf{p}}\ d\mathbf{p}
$$
and using cylindrical coordinates to obtain
$$
\frac{4\pi e^2}{k^2}\int\frac{\mathbf{k}}{\omega + i\Delta - \mathbf{k}\mathbf{v}}\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial \mathbf{p}}\ d\mathbf{p}=\\
\frac{8\omega_{Le}^2u}{\pi k^2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{kv_z}{\omega+i\Delta-kv_z}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{v_R}{(v_R^2 + v_z^2 + u^2)^3}\ dv_Rdv_z, 
$$
where $z$ axis is chosen to be parallel to $\mathbf{k}$.
This is much easier to solve using contour integration then the integral obtained in spherical coordinates. And it evaluates to exactly the answer from the textbook.

However, I still don't know what went wrong in my spherical attempt, everything seemed right to me.

I will mark this answer as a solution tomorrow.

Comment: It would be better if you edited this to be a stand-alone answer, and added comments on your original question as a thank-you.  In general, it's preferred on this forum to have answers only address the question at the top of the page;  interactions with other users are best confined to comments.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert OK, thanks, I've edited the answer